# after jquery success, javascript replace url, screen moves specified element id of page ... but screen moves to top location again

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

if `$list[$i][wo_status]` has no value,
I call whatson_read function,
it do ajax for db operation.
after success url reokaced
screen location moves to location of element id specified.

but after few micro second, secreen moves to top location.
why this happens?

**php section**

```
      if ($list[$i][wo_status])
          echo "<a href='" . $list[$i][url]  . "' $target_link >";
      else
          echo "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:whatson_read(\"" . $list[$i][url] . "\", " . $list[$i][wo_id] . "); return false' >";
```

**Javascript section**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function whatson_read(url, wo_id) {

    var post_url = "<?=$g4[bbs_path]?>/ajax_whatson.php?w=r&wo_id="+wo_id;
    var data = "";

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:post_url,
        data:data,
        async:false,
        error:function() {
            alert('fail');
        },
        success: function(){
            <? if ($target) { ?>
        parent.<?=$target?>.location.href = url ;
            <? } else { ?>
        location.href = url;
        <? } ?>
        }
     });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use `<a href="javascript:">`. That's an old, outdated practice.

Currently, your link is pointing to the in-page anchor `#`. That anchor doesn't exist on the page, so when you click the link, the browser just takes you to the top of the page.

You need to `return false` from your `onclick` handler to prevent the default action of the click event. This is conventional in JavaScript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="whatson_read(...); return false;">
```

Comment: Of course, attaching JavaScript event handlers directly on HTML elements is also pretty outdated, but a discussion of unobtrusive JavaScript is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks Brandan, I changed but the same situation. Screeen moves to half of page, then goes to top. ` 
              echo "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:whatson_read(\"" . $list[$i][url] . "\", " . $list[$i][wo_id] . ");return false;' >"; `

Comment: Can you post an example value of `$list[$i][url]`.

Comment: example of $list[$i][url] is [link](http://site_url/bbs/board.php?bo_table=freetalk&wr_id=881261#c_886110) anchor html <a name="c_886110" id="c_886110"></a> I think that may be IE bugs

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely in the `else` section of your PHP.

Replace `href='#'` with `href='javascript: void(0)'`

Comment: Thanks, Grexis. Same result. Screen moves to top from half of page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `javascript:;` rather than putting `#` in `href` attribute of `<a>` tag.

Also while `binding` `function` to links you can make that function `return false`, so that event is no further propagated. `Event propagation` makes the browser goto top of page.

Also there is no requirement to have `javascript:` text in your `onclick event`. `Html Onclick event` can directly accept javascript code.

Comment: Thanks linuxeasy. My code style is very old. I started program from FORTRAN. I changed and same result.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone.

I found your suggesstions are good for my program,
and my issue is due to IE bugs related anchor.
but, issue was not resolved.

http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3322666.htm

I changed

```
<a name="c_<?=$comment_id?>"></a>
```

to

```
<a name="c_<?=$comment_id?>" id="c_<?=$comment_id?>"></a>
```